# How to read and display a text file in to a <pre>, preserving line breaks, tabs and new lines?

Tags: jquery, file, text, display, formatted

I'm trying to load a text file to display in a `pre` tag using jQuery. I would like to display all the text including the escape sequences like new line, tab and so on. If I use `jQuery.get('log.cpp', function(data) { ...` and I try to display the text with:

```
var str = data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
$('#fileName').html(str);
```

Then many characters s like `<>` and the text surrounded by those chars are not displayed at all. Since I try to load and display some source code, a line with `#include <header>` will be presented as `#include` only.
If i try to use the following:

```
var str = data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\n');
$('#fileName').text(str);
```

No tabs or new lines are presented on screen and the text is shown as  one line only.

Any hint?
Thank you very much

Comment: Get rid of the `replace()` call and just use `text()`. Then the code will work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/vsx8tucj/

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, that lead me to find the error: the dynamically created html tag was "prev" instead of "pre".

Answer (score 0):

Just add this where you want to read or display it

```
style="white-space: unset;"
```

When you want to read

```
<textarea type="text" style="white-space: unset;"></textarea>
```

When you want to display

```
<pre style="white-space: unset;">Your text with line breaks</pre>
```